# Insert text a cursor position in to TinyMCE text editor

Tags: tinymce

I have a small function that allows a user to click a button under a textarea, and have the relevant text inserted (this works in conjunction with the jQuery `textrange` plugin).

However, because I'm using the TinyMCE editor in my plugin, this only works in 'Text' mode, not 'Visual'.

I've looked at the source, but can't figure out how to make it work for both. Does anybody know how I can insert text in to the editor when in 'Visual' mode? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var button_text = {} // The text to insert for each button click

    button_text['insert_event_name']            = 'event_name';
    button_text['insert_event_date']            = 'event_date';
    button_text['insert_event_start_time']      = 'event_start';
    button_text['insert_event_finish_time']     = 'event_finish';
    button_text['insert_event_location']        = 'event_location';
    button_text['insert_event_address_inline']  = 'event_address_inline';
    button_text['insert_event_address_blick']   = 'event_address_block';

    $('.inserter', '#event-desc-container').on('click', function(){

        var button = $(this).attr('name'),
            text = '['+button_text[button]+']',
            textarea = $('textarea#event_desc', '#event-desc-container');

        /** Get the location (start position) of where the cursor is in the textarea */
        var start = textarea.textrange('get', 'start');

        /** Add the relevent button text to the start position */
        textarea.textrange('replace', text).trigger('updateInfo').focus();

        /** The newly added text will be selected, so work out the end position of that selection */
        var end = textarea.textrange('get', 'end');

        /** Move the cart to the end position, so that no text is highlighted */
        textarea.textrange('set', end, 0).trigger('updateInfo').focus();

    });

});
```

Comment: Link to the jQuery plugin?

Comment: Anyway, this question is about Javascript and jQuery and off topic on this site.

Comment: Fair enough - As I uses TinyMCE with Wordpress, I tend to associate it with that by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this, I've added a button to one of the other meta boxes on the post edit/new screen, with an `id` of `addtxtbtn`. On `click`, I grabbed the `textarea`s inside the `#wp-content-editor-container`, which is the default wrapper for the default WP Editor instance. You might need to alter this, if you got different MarkUp. The rest is taken from the [demo on GitHub](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange/blob/master/demo.html) - in case this is the plugin you were talking about.

```
( function($) {
    $( '#addtxtbtn' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var textarea = $( '#wp-content-editor-container' ).find( 'textarea' );
        textarea.bind( 'updateInfo keyup mousedown mousemove mouseup', function() {
            var range = $( this ).textrange();
            console.log( range );
        } );
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

### Text

So in short: To add text to the "Text"-`textarea`, do the following:

```
$( '#wp-content-editor-container' ).find( 'textarea' ).val( 'Some default Text' );
```

### Visual

To add text to the "TinyMCE"/"Visual" editor, do the following:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand( 'mceInsertContent', false, 'Some default Text' );
```

If you need to get the content from TinyMCE, you can use the following:

```
// Raw
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent( { format : 'raw' } );
// HTML contents:
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

To get content from a specific TinyMCE instance (if more than one would be possible), use:

```
tinyMCE.get( 'some-id' ).getContent();
```

Comment: That is the plugin I was talking about, which is irrelevant to the question. I can already use that when in 'Text' mode, but the issue is in 'Visual' mode - no textarea is found, and therefore the text is not inserted. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard Then (1) go back and edit your question with a link to the plugin ... and (2) you're not talking about the `textarea`, but about the TinyMCE editor, right?

Comment: (1) Why is the plugin relevant?! I included the name of it so that people didn't look at the code and think 'That is not valid JS/jQuery'. It makes no difference. That code works for when the editor is in 'Text' mode, and I require help with 'Visual' mode. The code is so that people can see I tried! (2) Yes this is about TinyMCE, and as my comment above says (in response to your comment), it was an oversight on my part to put the question in this forum. I use Wordpress, I don't use anything else that incorporates TinyMCE, therefore my tiny brain associated them when I was asking the question!

Comment: ^^ And sorry if the above reads like a rant, it's not meant to be. I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: @DavidGard The plugin is relevant as it might have completely different ways to do things as one might expect. Also it's part of your question. Further, this is no forum, this is a Q/A site that archives questions for later readers who have the same problem. About the `textarea`: The problem is, that TinyMCE is _no_ textarea, so it was slightly confusing. See the update on how to insert data into both. Problem will be that your jQuery plugin won't be able to access TinyMCE content.

Comment: I assumed that was the problem, but had no idea how to fix. Your code for 'Visual' does the trick and inserts the text just where I want it. Thanks.